# Send Image and Form fields to an API with Angular5

Tags: angular, laravel, image

I have a form with 2 fields and 1 image fields.

```js
    public frontImageFile : File;

    selectFrontImage(event: any): void{
     if(event.target.files[0]) {      
        this.frontImageFile = event.target.files[0];
     } 
    }

    newCardForm = new FormGroup({
        first_name: new FormControl('')),
        email: new FormControl(''),
        image: new FormControl(''),
    });

    const cardData = new FormData();
    cardData.append('frontImage', this.frontImageFile, this.frontImageFile.name);
    const data = {
        first_name: this.newCardForm.value.first_name,
        email: this.newCardForm.value.email,
        image :cardData, 
    }
```

I am trying to send all there 3 fields information at a single API call.

my service

```js
    saveStoreCard(data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + sessionStorage.token);
        headers.set("content-type", "application/json");
        headers.append("accept", "application/json");
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        return this.http
            .post(`${this.SERVER_HOST}saveStoreCard`, data, options)
            .pipe(
                tap(
                    response => {   return response; },
                    error => {  this.loggedOutSet(error); }
                )
            );
    }
```

when I send image its retuning Null at server side.

Comment: Could you post your server side code please.

Comment: leave it about API and server, from front end values are not going in API Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have problem here

```js
const cardData = new FormData();
cardData.append('frontImage', this.frontImageFile, this.frontImageFile.name);
const data = {
  first_name: this.newCardForm.value.first_name,
  email: this.newCardForm.value.email,
  image : cardData, 
}
```

If you sending FormData you have to format all data using FormData so you have to change your code like this

```js
const cardData = new FormData();
cardData.append('frontImage', this.frontImageFile, this.frontImageFile.name);
cardData.append('first_name', this.newCardForm.value.first_name);
cardData.append('email', this.newCardForm.value.email);
```

Let me know if you still having any problem